# Can't drive GPIO_12 on Pi Zero 2

Tags: gpio

I'm having trouble driving GPIO12_PWM on a PI 2 Zero high (physical pin 32 on 40 pin connector). I can drive other GPIO pins low or high but not this one. I see that it is a PWM pin, so maybe that is my problem.

When I do the following in C++ the pin stays low. But if I use another GPIO then it will go high.

```
gpioSetMode(12, PI_OUTPUT); 
gpioWrite(12, 1);
```

I see it is low when probing with a scope and when I use:

```
raspi-gpio get 12
GPIO 12: level=0 fsel=1 func=OUTPUT
```

I also tried to drive it with `raspi-gpio` like this:

```
raspi-gpio set 12 op dh
```

but still it was low on the scope and `raspi-gpio get 12`.

I figure maybe I'm missing a setting or register here?

---edit
Interestingly enough this works fine on a RPI4. I know they're different chips and boards though.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the GPIO is bust.

With nothing connected to the expansion header run [gpiotest](https://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Testing).